# Array of Pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
int b[3][2] = { {0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5} };
int (*bpp)[2] = b;
int *bp = b[0];
```

At the above code: Is `*bpp` a pointer to a two-dimensional array? Or an array of pointers with the length of 2? Why is `*bpp` surrounded with parenthesis? Is there a difference between `*bpp[2]` and `(*bpp)[2]` ?

Meantime, in the following code: (Changing the dimension of the array)

```
int i[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int (*ap)[2] = (int(*)[2])i;
```

The second line is very confusing to me, especially the typecasting `(int(*)[2])`, what data type is it exactly casting to?

Thank you ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bpp` is a pointer to an array of two `int`. `*bpp` is an array of two `int`. `int *bpp[2]` would declare `bpp` as an array of two pointers to `int` (this parentheses make it be a pointer to an array of two `int`).

`(int(*)[2])` is a cast to a pointer to an array of two `int`.

These can be read by considering the "declaration follows use" rule (combined with knowledge of operator precedence):

```
  dereference (so bpp is a pointer)
     |
     v
int (*bpp)[2]
 ^         ^
 |         |
 |  array index (so the thing that bpp points to is an array)
 |
 the thing on the left is the final type... here it is int,
 so the array is an array of int
```